# Ace editor - shortcuts with double letters

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, shortcut

Right now, I'm working on key binds.

I have found, that I'm not able to make a key bind, which has two letters next to each other.
The key bind I'm trying to make, looks like this:

```
editor.commands.addCommands([{
                name: "test",
                bindKey: {
                    win: "Ctrl-K-D",
                    mac: "Command-K-D"
                },
                exec: function (editor, line) {
                    alert("test");
                },
                readOnly: true
            }])
```

It returns this error in the console: invalid modifier k in Ctrl-K-D

It doesn't seem to work. However, if I bind a function to say, Ctrl-Shift-A It works fine.

Is there a way to have a key bind with two letters next to each other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The shortcuts can only contain modifiers (Ctrl, Shift, Alt) and one key(A, J, 1, = etc.)

Comment: Do you intend to press all three keys together? There is a difference between [modifier keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key) and 'regular' keys; the latter are *not* meant to be pressed in combination.

Comment: I would like to have it, so that I hold down ctrl, then press K, then D.
Exactly like, say, Visual studio, or webmatrix does it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"Ctrl-K Ctrl-D"` if you want to allow pressing `D` when `K` is already released. There is no way yet to bind to a key the same way as to a modifier, that is allowing any order of `K` and `D` keys and requiring them to be pressed down at the same time.